# How do you redirect to an internal URL after submitting a form

Tags: 8, forms, redirection

I have tried to redirect after submitting.

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
   $form_state->setRedirect('mymodule');
   $form_state->setRedirectUrl(\Drupal\Core\Url);
}
```

I get the following error.

> Fatal error: Undefined constant 'Drupal\Core\Url'

Can anyone help me with the redirection?

Comment: I have added below code in my Submit form function at it worked.

$form_state->setRedirect('route');
return;